# Gmail does not load on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-workspace

I have an email with Google Apps for Domains.  It loads fine in every other other browser, but not IE8.  First it will sit there with the non-moving progress bar, saying Loading blah@blah.com.

Then after about 30 second or so, it'll say:

> Loading standard view | Load basic
>   HTML (for slow connections) This is
>   taking longer than usual. Try
>   reloading the page.
>
> If that doesn't work, you can:  Try
>   using https.  Disable Labs and try
>   again.  If you're on a slow
>   connection, try basic HTML view.  For
>   more troubleshooting tips, visit the
>   help center.

I'll click on the **Try reloading the page** link, which is the exactly the same URL that went to to begin with and it'll load just fine.

I've tried clearing cache, cookies, disabling all labs - nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shot in the dark - Try turning on **Tools | Compatibility View**

Comment: That was a good shot.  Unfortunately, nothing.

Comment: If this didn't help, you shouldn't mark it as correct (sorry Beaner), because people tend to skip answered questions when they are looking to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Javascript turned off?  I had a similar issue in Firefox when I had NoScript running and blocking the google pages.  Telling NoScript to allow everything on the site restored it.

Comment: Nope, JavaScript is on.  Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to load gmail the second time.

Answer (score 1):

I made one of those crazy discoveries that just can't be expected.  I haven't seen this solution anywhere else

I installed IE7 to fix the problem and it did.  But I wanted to run IE8.  So I went back to IE8 and my GMail no longer loaded and I just decided to give up on it.  Anyhow, I wanted the date yesterday and when I looked at the system clock (the little one on the status bar) it said it was October 31st.  Well that was obviously incorrect so I changed it to the correct date, and the next time I opened up IE8 my GMail worked.  This surprised me, and I thought about the fact that the only thing that had changed was the date.  So, I closed IE8, screwed up the date, and voila GMail is broken again.  Fixed the date again and GMail is fixed again, and this is unique to IE8 apparently.

I wonder if this would impress people at parties?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all add-ons, in Tools -> Manage Add-ons.

There are several add-ons that slow down IE8

Comment: Thanks for being specific... What in particular could be slowing down loading GMail?

Comment: I don't know, I've seen some machines being real slow to open and show some pages because lots of add-ons. But, of course, is just a guess, just something else to try

Comment: @AnonJr: Disabling all add-ons is a common method to figure out if it is in effect an add-on causing it. From that point, you can go divide and conquer. *We don't know what add-ons you are running...*

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? Are you at home or work?

I ask because I've noticed a similar problem periodically at work, but never at home. Both systems were* XP SP3, IE8.

*I have since moved all my home computers to the Windows 7 RC and am loving it. :)\

**Addendum**: Since you have stated you are at work, and not behind a proxy, do you know if they use any type of 3rd party DNS system? Or some sort of traffic monitoring/filtering system? Shouldn't make a difference, but you never know...

Also, I'm assuming you're using http://mail.google.com/ - while it shouldn't make a difference, do you see the same behavior using http://www.gmail.com/ ?

Comment: I am at work, but not behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it disappeared after Windows Update. Try downloading new updates, especially IE8 compatibility patches.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your IE Cache there might be something funny in there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now, but see my similar question here (with good solution):
[Gmail will not load](https://superuser.com/questions/189826/gmail-will-not-load)