# PHP Web Proxy does not perform ajax requests properly

Tags: proxy, php, www

I have this problem
[Gmail will not load](https://superuser.com/questions/189826/gmail-will-not-load)
except with a web proxy, which lead me to do some testing.

I am using latest PHProxyImproved. After testing on my web app, it appears that all AJAX pulls do not work. This appears to be because the URLs are not generated properly. There are a bunch of errors in the Javascript console that looks something like this

```
function onLoadTimeout(){if(ssm)return;if(pr>lp){lp=pr;npc=0;loadTimeout=setTimeout(onLoadTimeout,1E4);return}var d=document;npc++;if(npc<2 loadtimeout="setTimeout(onLoadTimeout,1E4);GLOBALS[1]=(new" am js timeout top window sc gmail sl rld ssm="1;d.getElementById(" stb style display="none" if jsl cb gm start time si jscc jsle apsl function new image src="?ui\x3d2\x26view\x3djsle\x26ik\x3d" date gettime x26zx x3ddgqpj5r7c51w apsc x3dmy9umejxfas2 i globals 9 x26imp x3d x26val pr x26random fp w focus var /script>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

basically it looks like it's messing up the URLs

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: More detail please. What error code(s) do you get back to the AJAX requests? Are you getting any content, possibly an HTML error in the response rather than XML?

Comment: updated description

Comment: Make your function write the entire output somewhere (into a DIV or into an alert or similar); see what the server is returning in full.